# HD 7870 won't support more then one monitor

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, vga, dvi

It appears as though my videocard won't support one then one monitor at a time. I've tried switching cables but basically if one goes out the other one comes on and the other one is disabled....Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong. I have [this card](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814127722&nm_mc=TEMC-RMA-Approvel&cm_mmc=TEMC-RMA-Approvel-_-Content-_-text-_-). I have two monitors with VGA cables connected via a converter to the mini display ports. I've also swapped out for a VGA for a DVI and the same things happen. I tried uninstalling cataylst and the driver and now it just makes whatever the 2nd screen is flicker on and off...

Comment: does the VGA to DP adapter work at all? have you tested it by itself? is it a passive adapter, or active?

Comment: I mean I'm pretty sure it works because they BOTH worked at the same time. At one point. THEN the thing happened where only one worked let's say the right side only worked. so when i went to switch the adapters and unplugged the one that worked first to switch it. My screens switched and all of the sudden the left on turned on and then i plugged the same cable back into the same monitor and all of sudden now that is the monitor with the problem.... so i think it's a video card issue. :(

Comment: whats the maximum amperage on the power supply it's connected to? or, if you can't figure out, what model power supply is it?

Comment: it's 650W [link](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817182263&nm_mc=TEMC-RMA-Approvel&cm_mmc=TEMC-RMA-Approvel-_-Content-_-text-_-)

Comment: well it's definitely not your powersupply. Have you installed the drivers for it?

Comment: Drivers for..? The video card? I reinstalled actually.

Comment: Thank you for all the help kind sir. It appears that the Resolution settings were far to high. I guess it couldn't push that amount of pixels to both monitors. So I turned them down and the shutting off and on stopped. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for reference for anyone else I wanted to compile a list of things that helped me with my problems with a second monitor. Just for reference I had a HD 7870 w/ AMD proccessor. Using VGA to mini display port converter and both monitors were the same.

**Problem:** The 2nd monitor would only display a "Check Connection" error message stating to check my VGA cable and the 1st monitor was fine.

**Solution**:

1. Uninstalling Drivers and Catalyst Software
2. Restarting PC
3. Re-installing drivers/Catalyst Software
4. Restarting PC
5. Under Performance tabs turning off any "Booster" including CPU/GPU/video card
6. At this point my monitor flickered on and off and was resolved by turning the resolution from over 1080p to slightly lower resolution on both monitors.

I believe the resolution was the final nail in the coffin because if I turn the resolution back up to max the problem where the 2nd monitor will turn off and on continues again.

**Special Note:** Before I re installed the drivers I did actually re-seat the graphics card within another PCI slot just to be safe :)